# Can't install tensorflow-macos on MacM1 (errors while installing grpcio)

Tags: macos, tensorflow, apple-m1

This has been a long fight trying to install tensorflow in Mac Mini M1...
I'm using macOS Monterey(12.0 Beta)
According to the last instructions from tensorflow/apple (https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/), I'm using miniforge conda, create a blank environment and then do the following:

```
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
```

Everything goes ok but then when I do the next step everything breaks:

```
python -m pip install tensorflow-macos
```

- Tried with python3.8 with the following error (summary, not the full logs):

  ```
   distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio
  ```
- Tried with python3.9 with the following error (summary, not the full logs):

  ```
    distutils.errors.CompileError: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio
  ```
- Tried with force reinstall and no-cache-dir `(python -m pip install tensorflow-macos --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall)` with the following error :

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/tf38/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-install-djre1j5j/numpy_48546adcbc9d4c558a4dc32a8e607649/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-install-djre1j5j/numpy_48546adcbc9d4c558a4dc32a8e607649/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-record-343ln54c/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-1fyu7c9t/normal --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-1fyu7c9t/normal/include/python3.8/numpy Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
  WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/81/20d5d994c91ed8347efda90d32c396ea28254fd8eb9e071e28ee5700ffd5/h5py-3.1.0.tar.gz#sha256=1e2516f190652beedcb8c7acfa1c6fa92d99b42331cbef5e5c7ec2d65b0fc3c2 (from https://pypi.org/simple/h5py/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/tf38/bin/python /private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-standalone-pip-nmsgrvml/**env_pip**.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-1fyu7c9t/normal --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'numpy==1.12; python_version == "3.6"' 'Cython>=0.29; python_version < "3.8"' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version == "3.7"' 'numpy==1.19.3; python_version >= "3.9"' 'numpy==1.17.5; python_version == "3.8"' pkgconfig 'Cython>=0.29.14; python_version >= "3.8"' Check the logs for full command output.
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement h5py~=3.1.0 (from tensorflow-macos) (from versions: 2.2.1, 2.3.0b1, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0b1, 2.4.0, 2.5.0, 2.6.0, 2.7.0rc2, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0, 2.10.0, 3.0.0rc1, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.3.0, 3.4.0)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for h5py~=3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I am fighting with M1 Mac Pro but on Big Sur. What worked for me - make sure you are working with arm64 terminal environment and that you have installed Homebrew for it. Then just run:

```
brew install gcc
```

After you restart the terminal (just in case) aka closing it and opening a new one, should be installed without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following code line

```
SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=0 python -m pip install tensorflow-macos
```

For a short tutorial on installation [refer this](https://medium.com/@aaparikh_/setting-up-apple-silicon-devices-to-allow-tensorflow-use-native-gpu-for-data-science-60a355c7d008)